# Using scope which can be shared between all components in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

I have simple controller with one method:

```
app.controller('MyApp', function($scope) {
     $scope.myMethod() {...}
}
```

I have also many components for input fields (for example for text input, number input, checkbox, radio etc.):

```
app.component('TextInput', {
    template: "<input type='text' ng-change='$ctrl.myMethodInComponent()' ng-model='inp' />",
    bindings: {
        myMethod: '&',
    },
    controller: function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.myMethodInComponent = function() {
            /* some customizations */
            ctrl.myMethod();
        }
    }
});
```

I create this input in following way:

```
<text-input myMethod="myMethod()"></text-input>
```

Everything works as expected, but the problem is that I have many components which want to use method 'myMethod' from main controller and I don't want to transfer it to each component using bindings ('&').
Rather I want to have this method in something like mainScope. I know that Angular provides rootScope but I don't have idea how to use it in my case. Is there possibility to attach 'myMethod' to some main (root) scope which will be shared between all my components?

Comment: make a service and attach that function to service and call the method using the service.

Comment: Look into using the `ng-form` directive and the [AngularJS form.FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) for processing `ng-change` events from multiple input elements. The form controller provides a common object based on the form name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved by using services and factories. Take alook into it, and if you need help or a template, just ask me.

**EDIT** template

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($scope)
    var ret = {
        myMethod: myMethod,
        myMethodWithParams: myMethodWithParams
    }
    return ret;

    function myMethod() {...}
    function myMethodWithParams(param1, param2) {...}
}
```

And now, in your controllers, you can use it as a dependency

```
app.controller('myController', function(myFactory) {
    var x = myFactory.myMethod();
    var y = myFactory.myMethodWithParams('hello', 'world');
});
```

Comment: comment section is under the question

Comment: Yes but if he asks for help, I can edit this message and put some code into it, as I suggested I could "give a template". But thanks for the help, I guess.

Comment: That would be appropriate. Thanks

Comment: What if this shared functions need some objects which are not in component's scopes? I mean: is there possibility to have some global variables (stored in something like rootScope) which can be used both in above service and in other controllers?

Comment: Following John papa's guidelines, I tend to avoid using scope. I only use it for broadcast and emit. This is best practice, if you want to use a global variable, do it, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the sort of use case you are looking for using $rootScope, but here's a solution along those lines:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello from Controller 1';

        $scope.$watch('message', function () {
            $rootScope.$emit('controller1_scope_change', {
                message: $scope.message
            });
        });

    }).controller('MyController2', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello from Controller 2, here is the output from Controller 1:';

        $rootScope.$on('controller1_scope_change', function (event, args) {
            console.log('arguments received by the handler for the event: ', args);
            $scope.message2 = args.message;
        });

        // really hacky way of doing it
        /*var controller1_scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('#controller1')).scope();
        controller1_scope.$watch(function () {
            $scope.message2 = controller1_scope.message
        });*/
    });
```

[View example here on codepen](http://codepen.io/david-j-davis/pen/ZBJGdb)